# How to show/hide data from a table in Powerpoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, hide, show

I'm trying to have several slides with tables, each table has 3 columns, the last column is the "reference value" and I want it to be hidden during the presentation and show it only by pressing a button or a hyperlink, each row individually. I think it's possible because I'm really new at coding and I have managed to do it by changing the cell's text format from white (which is the table's background color)  to red, but I can only do it for all the tables at once, and I need individual values on each one of them. (I hope I'm making myself clear). This is what I have done so far:

```
Sub format()

Dim s As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oTbl As Table


For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides

For Each oSh In s.Shapes
    If oSh.HasTable Then
        Set oTbl = oSh.Table

       With oTbl.Cell(2, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
                    .Text = "4500-9000"
                     .Font.Size = 12
                    .Font.Color = vbRed
                End With
    End If
Next
Next s
End Sub
```

But this will change the same cell on every table I have, I want it to change specific cells in specific tables one by one, since they all have different valued. I know I could do this with animations, but I'd rather do it this way.

EDIT: It would be great if, instead of pressing a button, I could get the data by hovering the pointer over the empty cell, and have it hidden away again when I hover the cursor off the cell.

In any case, whenever I do any change to the presentation during slideshow, the change will still be there at the end, which means It would only work once and then I would have to fix and hide all the values again, is there a way to restore the changes done during the presentation when it ends?

Answer (score 0):

you could adpt your sub and call it from another procedure by passing a reference to the table and cell you want to process like this:

```
Sub FormatTableCell(oTbl As Shape, lRow As Long, lCol As Long)

  With oTbl.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = "4500-9000"
    .Font.Size = 12
    .Font.Color = vbRed
  End With

End Sub
```

For example:

```
With ActivePresentation    
  FormatTableCell .Slides(1).Shapes("MyTable"), lRow:=1, lCol:=1
End With
```

Regarding the triggers for hover over and hover out, this is a tricky aspect of PowerPoint. There IS a trigger to run code when hovering over a shape but there is NOT a trigger for hovering out of a shape. To achieve the latter, you could put a transparent rectangle in the back layer of your slide and use that to spoof the hover out trigger by linking a hover over macro to it. Write your code and use the **Insert** / **Action** / **Mouse Over** function to trigger your VBA procedure with a signature like this:

```
Public Sub FormatThisTable(oTbl As Shape)
```

Note that this method only passes the shape (a table in your case) and not the cell the mouse is hovering over. The only way I can see you could achieve that would be to use a lot of very complex Windows APIs to detect the mouse cursor position relative to the table's on-screen coordinates.

Alternative approaches could either be to ungroup the table to a set of separate shapes or create cover shapes for each cell you need to show/hide and manage their visibility properties using the mouse in/out technique above.

For the last point, you will need to use application level events which requires code in a class module and this a good article to show you how:

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm

Comment: It displays an error "My table not found in the shapes collection"

Comment: The example I gave assumes you have named the table so that it may be identified in code. To do this, press Alt+F10 to open the Selection Pane. Select the table and then in the Selection Pane, set the name exactly the same as in the code e.g. "MyTable" (or anything else you want). You can refer to a shape either by it's name property or it's index. The problem with using name is that a user can change it so it's not 100% fool proof. You could use tags which are only accessible via code but it's a bit more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1
Launch PowerPoint and open the PPTX file that contains the rows you want to hide. Click the appropriate slide in the Slides pane to the left of the screen.
Step 2
Double-click the spreadsheet on the slide, which will allow you to edit it. Select the rows that you want to hide. Click the “Home” tab and locate the “Cells” section. Click the “Format” option, which will display a list of available features.
Step 3
Place the pointer over the “Hide & Unhide” listing in the “Visibility” section. Click the “Hide Rows” option to hide the selected rows. Click outside the spreadsheet to return to the PowerPoint slide.